# How do I see the exact position of my website in google SERP?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, search-results

Whenever I search with keyword in my computer, it shows my website in first page and in reality(other computers) it is not showing what I see in my computer, I understand that this is because of I visited the website so many times, but I want to see only the reality position, what should I do to see the reality ? and Is there any option for webmasters to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you using private navigation on Chrome to check the exact position. Also you can check rankings on Google WebMaster Tools. The last option will be to use an external tool, for example, Rankerizer or Serpbook.

Hope that helps.